# Gmail option menu is blocked underneath context menu of your specific browser when right clicking on email

Tags: gmail

I was conducting a search result for certain emails in my Gmail account I found them and began selecting each one I wanted to move to a certain area in my gmail

However there was no option to move them for there was no move to button presented

I did however see that if I right click after the annoying context menu shows up the Gmail option menu then shows up behind it preventing you from seeing the options of the Gmail menu

now I can press Esc which will remove the the context menu window, and only show the Gmail option menu window

but I am annoyed on the fact I shouldn't have to press Esc just to remove the context menu which is blocking my view of the Gmail menu window

I also shouldn't have to have the only way to see Gmail menu option window is by first seeing the context menu of my particular browser Firefox

So thats where I come asking for help on how I can get the Gmail menu option window without having to get also first the context menu of Firefox because it is incredibly annoying that this happening

so if anyone could please help me I would be very thankful

[image: Visually explaining my issue]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a Gmail question.  OP appears to be running a browser (FireFox?) 
that has been modified to trigger this behavior.  The Gmail web app replaces the usual Windows right-click menu with an app-specific menu.

Comment: Re *"I shouldn't have to press Esc"*: Commonly used sequences (including using modifier keys like Shift and Ctrl) can be collected into key sequences on a [macro keyboard](https://keyboardsexpert.com/macropad-mechanical-keyboard-faqs/) or [macro pad](https://keyboardsexpert.com/macropad-mechanical-keyboard-faqs/) (e.g., repurposing the [numeric keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad) as a macro pad (nothing to purchase if you don't have a crippled keyboard)). If mouse actions are supported in macros, they can be included as well. Though it has nothing to do with this web site.

Answer (score 2):

When you get the double menu, press the ESC key. This is a browser issue, not a gmail issue. It happens on many websites when there are two sources of a right-click menu.

Comment: OP indicated in post they are aware of this option but pressing the ESC key is too much work for them.